# multicheckbox class not loading

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I just moved my zend application to a new server and i'm getting an error on a call to zend_form_element_multicheckbox.  Here is the error:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/Form/Element/Multicheckbox.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form_Element_Multicheckbox' not found in /home/giantdev/paygiant/application/modules/admin/models/FormOrder.php on line 179
```

When I got the error, I tried uploading the fine to my zend framework library, but it was already there. What else do I need to do to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you check the file name case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you moved the code from a windows server to a UNIX server which is case sensitive.

It should be `Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` not `Zend_Form_Element_Multicheckbox` (note the `c`)